# Drools Decision Table with java variables

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools

How can I use just fields instead of objects in drools decision table?

For example, I have this method in the controller

```
@PostMapping("/order")
public Order checkDiscount(@RequestBody Order order) {
    session.insert(order);
    session.fireAllRules();
    return order;
}
```

and my decision table looks like this

| RuleSet | rules |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| import | com.example.drools.model.Order |  |
|  |  |  |
| RuleTable OrderDiscount |  |  |
| Name | CONDITION | ACTION |
|  | order : Order |  |
|  | order.getCard()==($param) | order.setDiscount($param) |
|  |  |  |
|  | "MasterCard" | 5 |
|  | "Visa" | 15 |

But I need to get field instead of an object:

```
@PostMapping("/order")
public Order checkDiscount(@RequestParam String card) {
    Order order = new Order();
    session.insert(card);
    session.insert(order);
    session.fireAllRules();
    return order;
}
```

What should my decision table look like then?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "need to get field", but your code shows that you're inserting a `String card` into working memory. So just update your code to use that.

eg. in addition to:

```
order: Order
```

Also declare your String-type input:

```
card: String
```

and compare as you would normally, replacing the `order.getCard()...` cell.